# Corrupted variable values in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading

Ok. I misunderstood a concept of mutexes a little bit. But i still have a strange problem. I simplified a code without using any fancy libraries, now it supposed to create a new user every 2 seconds:

Here is **User** class which does nothing, but displaying when it has started and its id:

```
class User: public std::thread {
    static int nextID;

    std::mutex *mutex;
    int id;

    void run(void);

public:
    User(std::mutex *mutex);
};

int User::nextID = 0;

void User::run(void) {
    mutex->lock();
    std::cout << "User thread entered, id: " << id << std::endl;
    mutex->unlock();
    while(true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

User::User(std::mutex *mutex)
        : mutex(mutex), id(nextID++), std::thread(&User::run, this) {
}
```

Here is **UserDispatcher** class that creates new User every 2 seconds, and stores it inside stl list container *users*.

```
class UserDispatcher: public std::thread {
    static std::mutex mutex;
    static std::list<User> users;

    void run(void);
    void addUser(void);

public:
    UserDispatcher(void);
};

std::mutex UserDispatcher::mutex;
std::list<User> UserDispatcher::users;

void UserDispatcher::run(void) {
    std::cout << "Listener entered" << std::endl;
    while(true) {
        mutex.lock();
        std::cout << "New user" << std::endl;

        users.push_back(User(&mutex));    //Works
        addUser();                        //Don't work

        mutex.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    }
}

void UserDispatcher::addUser(void) {
    users.push_back(User(&mutex));
}

UserDispatcher::UserDispatcher(void)
        : std::thread(&UserDispatcher::run, this) {
}
```

Simple *main()* function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    UserDispatcher userEngine;

    while(true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

It works when the **User** is created directly inside *run()* function of **UserDispatcher**, but if i simply enclose this line inside *addUser()* function program outputs that it has created all users with *0* id.

Comment: Don't use pointer to mutexes, but just mutexes, i.e. `std::mutex mutex;` inside your `class User`

Comment: @Basile but OP needs only one mutex. Pointer to mutex seems fine to me.

Comment: Your code is quite long. Can you make it shorter?

Comment: If you want a global mutex for `User` declare it as `static std::mutex globmutex;` inside `class User`

Comment: @Basile that object already exists as `UserListener::mutex`. All `User::mutex` pointers point to it.

Comment: Might not be related to your current problem but inheriting from `std::thread` disturbs me.  Did you learn this from Java?  I wouldn't do it (in either language, btw).

Comment: But I have to share mutex between userListener and users in order for it to work, so pointer is rather required.

Why not inheriting?

Comment: Your thread starts befor the member 'id' is initialized

Comment: Exactly what i think, but why? The constructor is called in a locked part of code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
User::User(std::mutex *mutex)
    : mutex(mutex), runUser(true), std::thread(&User::processThread, this) {
    id = nextID++;
}
```

`std::thread(&User::processThread, this)` will start the new thread on processThread before the instruction `id = nextID++;` is executed.

A simple solution would be to have the thread as a member of your User class and to make sure that the member id is initialized before the thread. For instance something along these lines:

```
class User: {
    static int nextID;

    int id;
    std::mutex *mutex;
    bool runUser;
    std::thread this_thread;
    // ...
};

User::User(std::mutex *mutex)
    : id(nextID++), mutex(mutex), runUser(true), this_thread(&User::processThread, this)
{
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding something, but i placed creation of new User object within mutex-locked code part, so why is this thread starting to run?

Comment: @omicronns because thread's working function does not have its own lock. `User::process` does, but `User::processThread` does not, so `cout` is not inside lock.

Comment: I meant lock inside listen(), because it calls addUser(), which calls a constructor of User.

Comment: @omicronns `processThread()` runs in its own thread, and doesn't wait on the mutex.

Comment: A word of warning for those that don't copy the pattern in this answer exactly. The order of initialization in the initializer list will happen in the order the member variables are declared. That is, in some cases, `this_thread` could still be started without `id(nextID++)` happening first if you order their declaration differently than what is shown here.